# Matlab fscanf string read strange behavior

Tags: matlab, file, scanf, fopen

I'm trying to read a file in matlab using fscanf. The file is the dump of a some memory area in a microcontroller. I export it from the IDE and the encoding is 'ISO-8859-1'.

Here's one line from the file as I open it in matlab:

```
25 08 00 00 7E 05 00 00 08 08 00 00 85 05 00 00 0D 06 00 00 76 06 00 00 04 0C 00 00 FB 07 00 00
3A 06 00 00 0C 06 00 00 01 06 00 00 0C 06 00 00 C3 05 00 00 EF 05 00 00 05 06 00 00 FF 05 00 00
EF 05 00 00 FB 05 00 00 89 08 00 00 74 06 00 00 0D 06 00 00 FC 05 00 00 10 06 00 00 C3 05 00 00
C5 05 00 00 F2 05 00 00 81 05 00 00 1C 06 00 00 85 05 00 00 F0 05 00 00 C2 05 00 00 5F 05 00 00
```

([here](https://jmp.sh/j5jOHoj) the complete file)

And this is correct: same numbers I see in the IDE.
What I do is:

```
fileID = fopen('testdataadc.txt','r','n','ISO-8859-1');
% Read all characters excluding white spaces.
vecDump = fscanf(fileID, '%s' ,[25 Inf]);
fclose(fileID);
```

Where 'n' is for native endiannes: Your system byte ordering (default).
And now the first column in vecDump (which is a 25x64 char variable):

```
25060000F5080000F8070000F0050000E5050000FC060000EF06000000070000
```

The format is the one I expected, but values are wrong.
For example:

```
         25 08 00 00 becomes 25 06 00 00
         7E 05 00 00 becomes F5 08 00 00
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @CrisLuengo makes a good point, since the first number if right, suggest the data could be transposed. However would be easier if you post the file somewhere so we can try...

Comment: Thanks CrisLuengo for the hint. I checked but to me that is not the issue. 
@Justin I edited the post, hope the link works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `fscanf` is a 25x64 char matrix. The data from the file fills this matrix column-wise. If you look along the first column, you will see: "250800007E05", etc. Because the file has 64 non-space characters along each row, you should read the file into a 64xN matrix, and then transpose it:

```matlab
vecDump = fscanf(fileID, '%s', [64,Inf]).'
```

Now `vecDump` will look like your file, but without the spaces.

Comment: thank you very much. Still, to me this is odd. But I guess this is due to my little experience with file I/O

Comment: @a_bet: You need to realize that it is not a series of strings being read, but a series of characters. And the output is an array of characters.